# Passing javascript variables to flutter web components?

Tags: javascript, flutter

Is there a way to pass javascript variables into flutter web components? I am trying to determine if we can use flutter to build components into existing web app. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes through [flutter_js](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js) and [js](https://pub.dev/packages/js) you integrate your JavaScript into your Flutter code.